# magento price getPrice() value

Tags: php, magento

```
function getDescriptionHtml($tpl, $p){
    $out = "";
    $pr = $p["product"];

    if(Mage::getStoreConfig('featuredproducts/displayoptions/title') == 'description'){
        $out .= "<ins><h4>{$pr->getName()}</h4></ins>";
    }
    $out .= "<span class=\"description\"".
            (!Mage::getStoreConfig('featuredproducts/displayoptions/description') ?
                    "style=\"display:none;\""
                :
                    ""
            )
            .">{$p['description']}</span>";
    $out .= "<ins><div>".
            (Mage::getStoreConfig('featuredproducts/displayoptions/price') ?
                    "<span style=\"font-size:45px\">{$pr->getPrice()}</span>"
                :
                    ""
            )       
            ."".
            (Mage::getStoreConfig('featuredproducts/displayoptions/bnb') ?
                    "<div><button style=\"postion:relative;margin-left:80px;margin-top:140px\" class=\"form-button\" onclick=\"setLocation('{$p["url"]}')\"><span>{$tpl->__('Buy Now')}</span></button></div>"
                :
                    "")
            ."
            </div></ins>";
    return $out;        
}
```

Per the code shown, when I'm using $pr->getPrice() its output looks like 299.0000, but I want it to be like 299.00. How can I do this?

Comment: If you find any one answer as the correct one amongst the below given answers, please click on the "tick" option available to the left hand side of that answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try [number format](http://be.php.net/function.number_format)

```
"<span style=\"font-size:45px\">{" . number_format($pr->getPrice(), 2) . "}</span>"
```

Comment: but is not the best solution, because prices should always use the internal price functions of Magento to garant compatibility

Answer (score 43):

Why not give this a try...

```
Mage::helper('core')->currency($pr->getPrice());
```

It gives you a currency symbol too.

Answer (score 20):

```
Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getFinalPrice(),true,false);
```

- "true" for price format.
- "false" for no html.

this i did in Magento 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 2):

or

```
sprintf("%0.2f",$_product->getFinalPrice());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "round" as number format doesn't always work correctly, depending on the location and currency formatting:

```
<span style=\"font-size:45px\">{" . round($_product->getFinalPrice(),2) . "}</span>
```